# Shell script not working to open LimeChat through the terminal

Tags: shell-script, osx

I created a shell script that I will execute in the morning to open up all the apps that I want

**startup.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

open /Applications/Firefox.app &
open /Applications/Messages.app &
open /Applications/iTerm.app &
open /Applications/Screenhero.app &
open /Desktop/LimeChat.app &

exit 0
```

The other apps work. But not the LimeChat application. I get this error:

```
The file /Desktop/LimeChat.app does not exist.
```

It does not show up in my applications folder, it only shows up in the desktop Desktop. And here it is very clearly on my desktop.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think the path is something other than /Desktop/LimeChat.app. That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @slm ok so apparently there needed to be a `~` before the path. So I did `~/Desktop/LimeChat.app` and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Why don't you write that up as your own answer and then mark it as accepted!

Comment: well technically the answer came from @Slyx, so I will first wait for him for make edits as the credit is due to him. If he does not, then I will add it.

Comment: Sure I was just looking to make sure that your Q gets the loop closed and has a A to go along with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly you mean `~/Desktop/LimeChat.app`. The `~` character refers to your home directory, so it will look for the `Desktop` folder in your home directory (e.g. `/home/jgallardo`), rather than the root.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using OSX (please remember to specify your OS next time). Your Desktop is not `/Desktop` it is probably something like

```
/Users/JGallardo/Desktop
```

So, you want to modify your script to point to the location of your actual `Desktop` folder:

```
open /Users/JGallardo/Desktop/LimeChat.app &
```

or

```
open ~/Desktop/LimeChat.app &
```

On *nix systems, the `~` is shorthand for your home directory (also written as `$HOME` in most shells). Therefore, `~/foo` is the same as `/Users/JGallardo/foo`.

Comment: yes on OSX and thank you for pointing that out.